# How to repeat a dynamic string in PHP

Tags: php, string, for-loop

I have a dynamic  created by PHP which produces different squares with   unique sizes and colors. Now, I want to output 100 of these squares to appear on the screen.

I have tried to put my code in a `for` loop but it does not work:

```
<?php 
$random_number = rand(10,100);
$color_array=array("yellow"=>"0","red"=>"1","green"=>"2","blue"=>"3","black"=>"4","brown"=>"5", "gray"=>"6");
$random_color = array_rand($color_array,1);
$x= '<div style="width:' . $random_number . 'px;height:' . $random_number . 'px;background-color:' . $random_color . '">';
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo $x;
}
?>
```

There are no error messages, but only one square appears instead of 100.

Comment: You're computing `$x` only once, before your loop. You'll want the random number generation to occur at every iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables `$random_number, $random_color and $x` must be redeclared inside your loop.
The reason why you were seeing only one `div` its because you forgot to close it. It was still generating them but inside one another.

```
<?php

$color_array=array("yellow"=>"0","red"=>"1","green"=>"2","blue"=>"3","black"=>"4","brown"=>"5", "gray"=>"6");

for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
  $random_number = rand(10,100);  
  $random_color = array_rand($color_array,1);
  $x= '<div style="width:' . $random_number . 'px;height:' . $random_number . 'px;background-color:' . $random_color . '"></div>';
  echo $x;
}
?>
```

Otherwise you will only echo the same thing over and over again.

Comment: You need to close that div.

Comment: downvoted since your code overrides the $color_array with each iteration, absolutely no reason to do it !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
        $color_array=array("yellow"=>"0","red"=>"1","green"=>"2","blue"=>"3","black"=>"4","brown"=>"5", "gray"=>"6");

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
          echo '<div style="width:' . rand(10,100) . 'px;height:' . rand(10,100) . 'px;background-color:' . array_rand($color_array,1) . '"></div></br>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Downvoted because it makes no attempt to explain the code you just wrote. Fix that and I will gladly remove it :)